# Primefaces dialogbox popup refreshes the background and disapears

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces dialogbox for popup purpose. But everytime it gets opened the whole screen get refreshed automatically and the popup disappears.

```
 < p:dialog id="dialog" header="Select different user" styleClass="atf-header"          widgetVar="dlg" appendToBody="true">
    <ui:include src="searchpopup.xhtml" />
      </p:dialog>
     <h:panelGroup>
     <h:outputLabel value="#{I18N['Create_Ticket_for_other_users']}" styleClass="atf-header" style="width:600px"></h:outputLabel>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="search_section" layout="block"
       styleClass="atf-content-area atf-separarot-botton"  style="width:600px">   
         <h:panelGroup id="input_search_section" >
            <h:outputText id="name" value="Siddharth Mishra"    
            labelStyleClass="atf-label">
            </h:outputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="atf-right atf-inline-block">
        <p:commandButton id="btn_search" value="select different user"
            styleClass="atf-button-search" onclick="dlg.show()">
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Hi Cyd. If you create the `p:dialog` without the `ui:include` what happens? Try to create the dialog by putting all the content of the include inside dialog. Also post the code inside of the `ui:include`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `p:commandButton` is AJAX button (which is default in primefaces) which submits whole form. Add `type="button"` attribute to it so it will be just ordinary button which do some JavaScript (so called push button). Also I don't see where is `h:form` tag here. As you have `appendToBody="true"` in you `p:dialog` be shore that you don't encapsulate `p:dialog` inside `h:form`. You should have `h:form` inside `p:dialog` if it is necessary, and if it is not move `p:dialog` outside of `h:form`.